# How to create an HKQuantitySample from HKStatistics?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to process `HKStatistics` that are heart rates and create an `HKQuantitySample` so that I can append to a local array. I can't figure out what dates to use for `startDate` and `endDate`, currently I'm just using `Date()`but I would rather be more precise and use the actual sample's date.  `statistics.StartDate` just gives you the date that the statistic collection started, but not the date of the individual sample/statistic.  I see that the statistic also has a `mostRecentQuantityDateInterval()` property but not sure how to use it here.

```
 private func processStatistics(withStatistics statistics: HKStatistics?) {
        
        // Make sure we got non `nil` parameters.
        guard let statistics = statistics else {
            fatalError("no statistics in processStatistics")
        }
        
        
        // Dispatch to main, because we are updating the interface.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch statistics.quantityType {
            case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate):
                
                if let unwrappedQuantity = statistics.mostRecentQuantity() {
                    let statisticAsHKQuantitySample = HKQuantitySample(type: statistics.quantityType, quantity: unwrappedQuantity, start: Date(), end: Date())
                    
                    self.heartRateSamples.append(statisticAsHKQuantitySample)
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for: `mostRecentQuantityDateInterval()`

```
let interval = statistics.mostRecentQuantityDateInterval()
interval.start
interval.end
```